# (this == null) in C#!

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-bug

Due to a bug that was fixed in C# 4, the following program prints `true`.  (Try it in LINQPad)

```
void Main() { new Derived(); }

class Base {
    public Base(Func<string> valueMaker) { Console.WriteLine(valueMaker()); }
}
class Derived : Base {
    string CheckNull() { return "Am I null? " + (this == null); }
    public Derived() : base(() => CheckNull()) { }
}
```

In VS2008 in Release mode, it throws an InvalidProgramException.  (In Debug mode, it works fine)

In VS2010 Beta 2, it doesn't compile (I didn't try Beta 1); I learned that the hard way

Is there any other way to make `this == null` in pure C#?

Comment: It's most likely a bug in C# 3.0 compiler. It works the way it should in C# 4.0.

Comment: Yes, that should not compile at all IMO.

Comment: what the ...?! Who comes up with such ideas? Nevertheless an interesting bug, thanks for sharing

Comment: @SLaks: Problem with bugs is that you can expect them to be fixed at some point so finding them "useful" is probably not wise.

Comment: It should have been obvious that this was a bug, which should have kept you from relying on it.  Hopefully, you didn't rely on it :)

Comment: thanks! didn't know about LINQPad. it's cool!

Comment: In what way, exactly, is this useful?

Comment: how was this bug useful?

Comment: Hence the adage: "It's a feature not a bug." Microsoft is forced to tiptoe its code around developers who rely on such "features", breaking things and keeping other thing that way.

Comment: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property` for both compilers 3.5 and 4.0 under VS2010. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: @abatishchev: You're using VS2010.   This is a bug in the C# **3.0** compiler.   Even if you compile against .Net 2.0 on VS2010, you're still using the C# **4.0** compiler, which fixed the bug.

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks for mentioning! Anyway why can't i access an instance method from nested constructor call?

Comment: @abatishchev: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/02/don-t-let-this-get-away.aspx

Comment: Wait, how the heck can `this` ever be null?? Sounds like some kind of poltergeist.

Comment: Also, yeah, the usual way they'd deal with this (at least back when Jason Zander was the self-proclaimed "approver" of all bug-fixes in the CLR/BCL), would have been to leave the bug in in fear of it breaking code that abuses the bug. I for one am glad that they're not sticking to that philosophy as much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CS0120 error under vs2010 beta 2 - object reference is required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600001/cs0120-error-under-vs2010-beta-2-object-reference-is-required)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This observation has been posted on StackOverflow in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600001/cs0120-error-under-vs2010-beta-2-object-reference-is-required) earlier today.

[Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell)'s [great answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600001/cs0120-error-under-vs2010-beta-2-object-reference-is-required/1600328#1600328) indicates that according to the spec (section 7.5.7), you shouldn't be able to access `this` in that context and the ability to do so in C# 3.0 compiler is a bug. C# 4.0 compiler is behaving correctly according to the spec (even in Beta 1, this is a compile time error):

> **§ 7.5.7 This access**
>
> A *this-access* consists of the reserved word `this`.
>
> *this-access:*
>
> ```
> this
> ```
>
> A *this-access* is permitted only in the *block* of an instance constructor, an instance method, or an instance accessor.

Comment: I do not see, why in the code presented in this question, usage of keyword "this" is invalid. The method CheckNull is a normal instance method, **nonstatic**. Using "this" is 100% valid in such method, and even comparing this to null is valid. The error is in the base init line: it is the attempt to pass instance-bounded delegate as a parameter to the base ctor. This is the bug (a hole in sematic checks) in the compiler: it should NOT be possible. You are not allowed to write `: base(CheckNull())` if CheckNull is not static, and alike you should not be able to inline an instance-bound lambda.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: `this` in `CheckNull` method is legal. What is not legal is the **implicit** *this-access* in `() => CheckNull()`, essentially `() => this.CheckNull()`, which is running outside the **block** of an instance constructor.  I agree that the part of spec I cite is mostly focused on the syntactic legality of `this` keyword, and probably another part addresses this issue more precisely, but it is easy to conceptually extrapolate from this part of spec as well.

Comment: Sorry, I disgree. While I know that (and written that in the comment above) and you also know that - you have not mentioned the actual cause of the problem in your (accepted) answer. The answer is accepted - so seemingly the author grapsed it too. But I doubt that all readers will be as bright and fluent in lambdas to recognize a instancebound-lambda versus static-lambda at first sight and map that to 'this' and problems with emitted IL :) This is why I added my three cents. Aside of that, I agree with everything else what was found, analyzed and described by you and others:)

Answer (score 24):

The raw decompilation (Reflector with no optimizations) of the Debug mode binary is:

```
private class Derived : Program.Base
{
    // Methods
    public Derived()
    {
        base..ctor(new Func<string>(Program.Derived.<.ctor>b__0));
        return;
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private static string <.ctor>b__0()
    {
        string CS$1$0000;
        CS$1$0000 = CS$1$0000.CheckNull();
    Label_0009:
        return CS$1$0000;
    }

    private string CheckNull()
    {
        string CS$1$0000;
        CS$1$0000 = "Am I null? " + ((bool) (this == null));
    Label_0017:
        return CS$1$0000;
    }
}
```

The CompilerGenerated method doesn't make sense; if you look at the IL (below), it's calling the method on a null *string* (!).

```
   .locals init (
        [0] string CS$1$0000)
    L_0000: ldloc.0 
    L_0001: call instance string CompilerBug.Program/Derived::CheckNull()
    L_0006: stloc.0 
    L_0007: br.s L_0009
    L_0009: ldloc.0 
    L_000a: ret
```

In Release mode, the local variable is optimized away, so it tries to push a non-existant variable on to the stack.

```
    L_0000: ldloc.0 
    L_0001: call instance string CompilerBug.Program/Derived::CheckNull()
    L_0006: ret
```

(Reflector crashes when turning it into C#)

---

**EDIT**: Does anyone (Eric Lippert?) know why the compiler emits the `ldloc`?

Answer (score 11):

I have had that! (and got proof too)

[image]

Comment: Was late, was a sign I should stop coding  :)  Was hacking our with DLR stuff IIRC.

Comment: make a debugger visualizer (DebuggerDisplay) for whatever 'this' is, and make that fool you that's null? :D just sayin'

Answer (score 10):

This isn't a "bug".  This is you abusing the type system.  You are never supposed to pass a reference to the current instance (`this`) to anyone within a constructor.

I could create a similar "bug" by calling a virtual method within the base class constructor as well.

Just because you *can* do something bad doesn't mean its a **bug** when you get bit by it.

Comment: It is a compiler bug.  It generates invalid IL.  (Read my answer)

Comment: The context is static, so you should not be allowed an instance method reference at that stage.

Comment: You do something you should never do, then shiz breaks.  And that's a compiler bug?  Again, there are things you can do that you aren't supposed to do which will break, it doesn't mean that it is a bug because the compiler couldn't handle your acting badly.

Comment: @Will: It's a compiler bug. The compiler is supposed to generate *valid*, *verifiable* code for that code snippet or spit out an error message. When a compiler does not behave according to the spec, **it is buggy**.

Comment: The thing is if this is "fixed" in 4.0 then it is still broken, as `this` can never equal `null`.  Maybe it has to do with their shoehorning in the DLR?

Comment: @Will: "The thing is if this is "fixed" in 4.0 then it is still broken, as `this` can never equal `null`." Isn't it how it should be? Do you ever check `if (this != null)` in instance methods? C# programmers rely on `this` not being `null`. The old behavior did not implement the spec correctly.

Comment: @Will#4: When I wrote the code, I hadn't thought about the implications. I only realized that it didn't make sense when it stopped compiling in VS2010. –

Comment: @Will#3: What on earth do you mean?

Comment: By the way, the virtual method call in constructor is a completely valid operation. It's just not recommended. It *may* result in logical disasters but never an `InvalidProgramException`.

Comment: I try to stay away from valid operations that can result in logical disasters, heheh.

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure if your object is `null` there's never going to be a scenario where `this` applies.

For instance, how would you call `CheckNull`?

```
Derived derived = null;
Console.WriteLine(derived.CheckNull()); // this should throw a NullReferenceException
```

Comment: In a lambda in the constructor argument.  Read the entire code snippet.  (And try it if you don't believe me)

Comment: I agree although I do remember faintly something about how in C++ an object didn't have reference within it's constructor and I'm wondering if the (this == null) scenario is used in those cases to check whether a call to a method was made from the object's constructor before exposing a pointer to "this". Though, as far as I know in C#, there shouldn't be any cases where "this" would ever be null, not even in the Dispose or finalization methods.

Comment: I guess my point is that the very idea of `this` is mutually exclusive of the possibility of being null--sort of a "Cogito, ergo sum" of computer programming. Therefore your desire to use the expression `this == null` and ever have it return true strikes me as misguided.

Comment: In other words: I did read your code; what I'm saying is that I question what you were trying to accomplish in the first place.

Comment: This code simply demonstrates the bug, and, as you pointed out, is utterly useless.  To see real useful code, read my second answer.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
    public static T CheckForNull<T>(object primary, T Default)
    {
        try
        {
            if (primary != null && !(primary is DBNull))
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(primary, typeof(T));
            else if (Default.GetType() == typeof(T))
                return Default;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("C:CFN.1 - " + e.Message + "Unexpected object type of " + primary.GetType().ToString() + " instead of " + typeof(T).ToString());
        }
        return default(T);
    }
```

example: UserID = CheckForNull(Request.QueryString["UserID"], 147);

Comment: You _completely_ misunderstood the question.

Comment: I figured as much. Thought I'd try anyway.