# Can "this" ever be null in Java?

Tags: java, this

Saw this line in a class method and my first reaction was to ridicule the developer that wrote it.. But then, I figured I should make sure I was right first.

```
public void dataViewActivated(DataViewEvent e) {
    if (this != null)
        // Do some work
}
```

Will that line ever evaluate to false?

Comment: Always ridicule first and question later. It's easier to apologize than to recapture a golden opportunity to tear someone down in a flurry of brimstone.

Comment: I thought that too... Actually had to check the annotations to make sure it wasn't mine... How many times have I written:

Comment: +1 for the term "flurry of brimstone".

Comment: You know whats funny? This can happen in C# due to a compiler bug!

Comment: @Blindy will give +1 for code sample.

Comment: @Nathan: [I'll take](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1600662/54262) [that +1.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1600001/54262)

Comment: +1 for "make sure I was right first"

Comment: a little ridicule goes a LONG WAY :)

Comment: @Nathan Feger, Roger got it! :D

Comment: @Roger gave secret +1 somewhere. :)

Comment: well in C# it can be null. In some edge cases. I had the same impulse : ridicule the sucker but then I just calmed down. Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464097/why-doesnt-the-compiler-at-least-warn-on-this-null

Comment: Though it's very unlikely it can (dispite the general consensus) actually occurre that the test returns false

Answer (score 95, accepted):

No it can't. If you're using `this`, then you're in the instance so `this` isn't null.

The JLS says :

> When used as a primary expression, the keyword this denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed.

If you invoked a method from an object, then the object exists or you would have a `NullPointerException` before (or it's a static method but then, you can't use `this` in it).

---

**Resources :**

- [JLS - `this` keyword](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#251519)

Comment: Using it can, however, fail to compile.  If it compiles then it's safe to use.

Comment: Is it just nonsense to do such a check or is it actually prevented by the java language that such a thing can happen? I.e is the null pointer exception thrown before entering the method or only when a member is tried to be accessed? In comparable situations in other languages (in particular C++), this case is undefined behavior and the language will not actively prevent such a scenario.

Comment: I don't know deeply about Java, but in C++ the `this` of an instance method could be NULL. So I am not quite convinced this is a sufficient reason in Java.

Comment: @Mark Peters: What usages could fail to compile? Use in a static class is the only thing I can think of right now.

Comment: @Johannes: `this` will only compile when it is used in the context of an instance.  If somebody tries to call an instance method without giving an instance, it won't compile for *them*, or they'll get an NPE when trying to invoke it on an object.  Runtime behaviour is basically irrelevant here unless you do some crazy bytecode manipulation.

Comment: @Frustrated: In a static method or static initializer, yes.  Or the RHS of a static assignment+declaration.

Comment: the null pointer exception in something like `foo.bar()` would be thrown when `foo` is discovered to be `null`. it does happen before entering the method, but the real story is that there is no method to attempt to call.

Comment: @KennyTM: it is sufficient in Java.  If you're using the `this` keyword and it compiles, it's not null when you observe it.  But as others say that doesn't prevent an NPE when trying to invoke the method, e.g.  But that's completely out of your control as a method and a null check within the method isn't going to change anything.

Comment: @Kenny: Not without [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1844005/54262), though if you know your implementation's details, you could use it.

Comment: First time I've seen an incorrect answer with that many upvotes. It is indeed possible to create bytecode that will result in test being false

Comment: @Rune FS Then, is it still java ? (As a language)

Comment: @Colin what language the code _calling_ the above method is written in doesn't really affect what code the above code is written in does it?

Comment: *"It is indeed possible to create bytecode that will result in test being false"*.  However, unless those bytecodes can also be generated by *JLS conformant* Java compiler, AND loaded / run by a JVM (with the verifier enabled), then you are not talking about a genuine Java method.

Comment: I wouldn't subscribe to this definitive answer, even if it makes complete sense. I have crash reports for an Android app where this == null when an instance method is called right after the variable is being null-ified from another thread. The actual call goes through even if the variable is null, and it crashes when it tries to read an instance member :)

Answer (score 64):

It's like asking yourself "Am I alive?" `this` can never be null

Comment: _am_ I alive?! o god i don't know anymore

Comment: You're making it sound like `this != null` was self-evident. It isn't - in C++, for example, `this` may well be `NULL`, for a non-virtual method.

Comment: @nikie In some sense, it's self-evident. Even in C++, any program where this happens has undefined behavior. It can also happen for virtual functions on GCC: http://ideone.com/W7RmU .

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb It's not true that the behaviour of a c++ program with a null ref for this is undefined. It's defined as long as you do not dereference this

Answer (score 9):

**No never**, the keyword 'this' itself represents the current alive instance (object) of that class within the scope of that class, with which you can access all its fields and members (including constructors) and the visible ones of its parent class.

And, more interestingly, try setting it:

```
this = null;
```

Think about it? How can it be possible, won't it be like cutting the branch you are sitting on. Since keyword 'this' is available within the scope of the class thus as soon as you say this = null; anywhere within the class then you are basically asking JVM to free the memory assigned to that object in the middle of some operation which JVM just can't allow to happen as it needs to return back safely after finishing that operation.

Moreover, attempting `this = null;` will result in compiler error. Reason is pretty simple, a keyword in Java (or any language) can never be assigned a value i.e. a keyword can never be the left value of a assignment operation.

Other examples, you can't say:

```
true = new Boolean(true);
true = false;
```

Comment: I found this because I wanted to see if I could use `this = null`. My instance was in android where I wanted to remove a view and set the object handling the view to null. Then I wanted to use a method `remove()` which would remove the actual view and then the handler-object would be rendered useless, so I wanted to null it.

Comment: Not sure I agree with your claims.  (at least the middle part; the lvalue part is fine ... though I'm pretty sure there are in fact broken languages which allow you to assign e.g. true = false (and even languages I wouldn't call broken may allow it with Reflection or similar trickery)). Anyways, If i have some object foo and I were to do (ignoring that it's illegal) foo.this = null, foo would still point to the memory and so the JVM wouldn't garbage collect it.

Comment: @Foon well the question precisely talks about Java language, moreover, I haven't came across any language where setting this=null is allowed. That is, if there do exists such languages then I highly doubt that 'this' in such languages will have same context and ideology.

Answer (score 7):

If you compile with `-target 1.3` or earlier, then an *outer* `this` may be `null`. Or at least it used to...

Comment: I guess through reflection we can set the outer this to null. could be an April fool joke on someone when he got null pointer exception in referencing `Outer.this.member`

Comment: @irreputable might be of interest in deserialization to choose order of outer/inner object instantiation

Comment: @SamGinrich Oh that's an interesting point that no other answer appears to address. In Java Serialization, at least, the order fields are initialised during deserialisation is determined by the stream. OTOH, if that is causing a problem you have bigger issues.

Comment: @irreputable Actual came here with the order problem, when replacing standard ObjectInpput/OutputStream, which has hard dimension limits. Turned out, reflection can create an inner object "standalone" with Outer.this == null, transiently, and bind the Outer object later (certainly the behaviour is undefined if you do not!)

Answer (score 4):

No. To call a method of an instance of a class, the instance has to exist. The instance is implicitly passed as a parameter to the method, referenced by `this`. If `this` was `null` then there'd have been no instance to call a method of.

Answer (score 3):

In static class methods, `this` isn't defined since `this` is associated with instances and not classes. I believe it would give a compiler error to attempt to use `this` keyword in static context.

Answer (score 3):

It's not enough that the language enforces it. The VM needs to enforce it. Unless the VM enforces it you could write a compiler that does not enforce the null check prior to calling the method written in Java. 
The opcodes for a instance method invocation include loading the this ref on to the stack  see: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Compiling.doc.html#14787. Substituting this for a null ref would indeed result in the test being false

Answer (score 3):

A normal `this` can never be `null` in real Java code<sup>1</sup>, and your example uses a normal `this`.  See other the other answers for more details.

A qualified `this` *should* never be `null`, but is possible to break this.  Consider the following:

```
public class Outer {
   public Outer() {}

   public class Inner {
       public Inner() {}

       public String toString() {
           return "outer is " + Outer.this;  // Qualified this!!
       }
   }
}
```

When we want to create an instance of `Inner`, we need to do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Outer outer = new Outer();
    Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
    System.out.println(inner);

    outer = null;
    inner = outer.new Inner();  // FAIL ... throws an NPE
}
```

The output is:

```
outer is Outer@2a139a55
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Outer.main(Outer.java:19)
```

showing that our attempt to create an `Inner` with a `null` reference to its `Outer` has failed.

In fact, if you stick within the "Pure Java" envelope you cannot break this.

However, each `Inner` instance has a hidden `final` synthetic field (called `"this$0"`) that contains the reference to the `Outer`.  If you are really tricky, it is possible to use "non-pure" means to assign `null` to the field.

- You could use `Unsafe` to do it.
- You could use native code (e.g. JNI) to do it.
- You could do it by using reflection.

Either way you do it, the end result is that the `Outer.this` expression will evaluate to `null`<sup>2</sup>.

In short, it **is possible** for a qualified `this` to be `null`.  But it is **impossible** if your program follows the "Pure Java" rules.

---

<sup>1 - I discount tricks such as "writing" the bytecodes by hand and passing them off as real Java, tweaking bytecodes using BCEL or similar, or hopping into native code and diddling with the saved registers.  IMO, that is NOT Java.  Hypothetically, such things might also happen as a result of a JVM bug ... but I don't recall every seeing bug reports.</sup>

<sup>2 - Actually, the JLS does not say what the behavior will be, and it could be implementation dependent ... among other things.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

If the method is static, then there isn't any `this`. If the method is virtual, then `this` cannot be null, because in order to call the method, the run-time will need to reference the vtable using the `this` pointer. If the method is *not virtual* then, yes, it is possible that `this` is null.

C# and C++ allow non-virtual methods, but in Java all non-static methods are virtual, so `this` will never be null.

Comment: "in Java all non-static methods are virtual, so `this` will never be `null`" That's what "convinced" me the most. Since methods are by default overridable, the JVM must have a way to know which precise subclass we're calling a method on: this requires having a non-null object pointer. If all classes were concrete or their methods final, it would be possible to rely solely on static dispatch and have a null `this` (granted the spec would allow it).

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke a method on `null` reference, the `NullPointerException` will be thrown from Java VM. This is by specification so if your Java VM strictly complies to the specification, `this` would never be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr, "this" can only be called from a non-static method and we all know that a non-static method is called from some sort of object which cannot be null.