# Is there option that this can be null?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can “this” ever be null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789528/can-this-ever-be-null-in-java)

I have thread with thic code:

```
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      process();
    } finally {
      Factory.close(this);
    }
  }
```

is there option that `this` can be `null` ?

Comment: Factory could be null...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
is there option that this can be null
```

**No.** `this` reference cannot be `null`. It will always point to the Thread instance currently executing that code.

Answer (score 0):

No nothing is  at least wrong here. THIS is never null in JAVA. May be your problem is somewhere else. Try to submit more code

Answer (score 0):

`this` cannot be `null` anywhere in Java, `null` means it points to no object, (it's just a junk *variable*). `this` means, **in the object, you are now implementing**, it should point to itself.