# Spring Boot Microservice com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I have created micro service using spring boot and implment zuul proxy so when I call url via zuul proxy and somehow my service is down I get **com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error** I have also implement **errorFilter** and send custom message from **errorFilter** but it's not working for me. I get below response:

```
{
"timestamp": 1537261710692,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException",
"message": "GENERAL"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customizing Zuul Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461493/customizing-zuul-exception)

Comment: You should add the custom exception handling code in question. Usually custom exception handling should fix that issue.

Comment: In it's present state, your question isn't specifying any new issue (it's same as the one mentioned in the above comment).

Answer (score 3):

This problem occurs when your back-end service is not available but your gateway make proxy calls to unavaiable back-end service.

If you read a log file, you can check it.

```
DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client BACKEND-YOUR-SERVICE initialized: 
DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=BACKEND-YOUR-SERVICE,
current list of Servers=[]
```

It means that there are not available servers of your back-end service.

Please check in the following order.

1. Check whether your back-end service is running
2. (If you use Eureka Server) Check whether your back-end service is registered on Eureka server on Eureka webpage.
3. Check whether your zuul proxy is configured with correct back-end service name.

Comment: So in case of service is not available how can I handle it like service not available using zuul?

Comment: Sorry. I can`t understand service not available using zuul.