# How to reduce delays when using zuul, eureka, feign

Tags: netflix-eureka, feign

When the API service is restarted initially. If I call the API service directly, it works but if I call it through the feign client, I'll see the hystrix fallback message for a few seconds. And If API service is not running when I call it through the zuul, I'll see the following error message:

> com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Hystrix Readed time out

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Though this particular problem is somewhat well-known, it is in general a good practice to add some stack-trace/code with your these type of questions. Helps in narrowing down the potential causes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Zuul throws exception when upstream service is not available instead of throwing 503/404. You need to extend `ErrorFilter` and handle the exception with custom behavior.

That's why when the API service is not running you get `ZuulException`.

This behavior has been discussed in detail in [Zuul swallows 503 exceptions from upstream microservices](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/406) GitHub thread.

Some of the approaches to deal with this exception is explain in this SO thread: [Customizing Zuul Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461493/customizing-zuul-exception).