# Spring - Changing Order of Global Error handler and Filter

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a filter like:

```
@Component
@Order(8)
public class LogReqFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
{
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
{...}
}

it basically logs all requests and responses. When there is a 400 error however the response is blank. There is a global exception handler that replaces the body with the custom error:

@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleArgNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex
            , HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {...}
}
```

I noticed that the Global Exception handler is called after the filter and I think that this is why the response is blank in the filter. Is there a way to have the filter called after the Global Exception Handler?

Comment: you should use `AOP` instead of filter

Answer (score -1):

Edited:

### TLDR

No You can't change the order as per the OP Title because your GlobalError Handler is always in the layer that holds the ControllerAdvices and that is always between the RequestFilter layer and the Controller.

### Long Version

You are somewhat right.

i refer you to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17716298/405749

expanding on this:

- be aware that before and after depends from which you are looking from, ie.

  - inbound (before it reaches your controller code) OR
  - outbound (after the controller is done)
- now you can plug in different components on this path, e.g. here RequestFilter and  Controller Advice
- depending on the method you implement, it gets called only on the inbound or outbound track or both, here:

  - `doFilterInternal()` is called inbound. Only if you call `filterChain.doFilter(request, response);` the request continues on the inbound track otherwise it stops here and the response is returned with whatever is already in its output stream or will be added by this filter or filters still be encountered on the way out
- this is the call sequence assuming we only have this filter and advice

  1. 'inbound'-methods from request filters
  2. 'inbound'-methods from controller advice(s)
  3. 'outbound'-methods from controller advice(s)
  4. 'outbound'-methods from request filters

Now, the `handleArgNotValid()` only gets called in case such an exception is thrown and potentially adds content to the Response-Output stream. Your example doesnt show if you return an object here or not, but i guess from your OP that you dont. and as a consequence the output stream is empty.

Plz also note, that there is no easy way to dump/look into the output stream unless you wrap it, but that's another topic.