# How to send back to client custom response in the case of an exception from a Spring filter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, filter, spring-security, filtering

What is the proper way to send back to client custom response in the case of an exception from a Spring filter? OR Is it possible at all?

I tried:

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595605/how-to-manage-exceptions-thrown-in-filters-in-spring) @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler are out of rich with Filters

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715921/exception-handling-for-filter-in-spring)  response.sendError(status, msg); just does nothing

[this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-exceptions)  absolutely no effect from these

and many many many other..

My security config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain mySecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers((requests) -> requests.antMatchers("/**"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll());
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The filter:

```
@Component
public final class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private TypeA typeA;
    private TypeB typeB;

    public MyFilter(TypeA typeA, TypeB typeB) {
        this.typeA = typeA;
        this.typeB = typeB;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                                                                                  throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            if (typeA.getCount() > 500 && typeB.getCount() > 400) {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
//                response.getWriter().write("some err");
//                response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "Unauthorized attempt.");
//                response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "Unauthorized .");
                throw new AccessDeniedException("Unauthorized attempt.");
            }
        }

    }
```

So - None of the above changes the default response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-09-28T14:04:39.657+00:00",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "path": "/api/some/path"
}
```

Is it possible to send back to client custom error message? I see a lot of people suggest Controller Exception Handling mechanisms, but they get in action only after the filter chain, when there is an exception from A CONTROLLER.

EDIT:
PS: Please, do not mark my question as duplicate - there are tens of such questions - the answers are not working for me.

Comment: you are getting a 403 because your request most likely gets stopped by CORS

Comment: @Toerktumlare 403 is correct - this what I want in case of un-wanted request. I cannot customize the error message and this is the problem. Read the question

Comment: @Toerktumlare, of course that you're not obligated to do anything. I was making it clear that your suggestion, in the first comment, is wrong.