# Using 'this' in constructors without throwing a NullPointerException

Tags: java, constructor, nullpointerexception, this

I want to create a class `Bar` such that every time I instantiate a `Bar`, it is added to an `ArrayList<Bar>` of an object `Foo`. This is what I have tried:

```
class Foo {
    private ArrayList<Bar> bars;
    .
    .
    .
    public ArrayList<Bar> getBars() { return bars; }
}

//in class Bar
class Bar {
    public Bar(Foo f) {
        f.getBars().add(this); //NullPointerException!
    }
}
```

I realize what is happening here (the constructor is not finished, so `this` returns `null`), but how can I avoid this?

Comment: The problem is not "this". The problem is that bars is not initialized. Do bars = new ArrayList<Bar>(); first in the class Foo (e.g. in its constructor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I realize what is happening here (the constructor is not finished, so this returns null), but how can I avoid this?

Your diagnosis is incorrect.

The value of `this` can never be `null`.  And that includes in a constructor.

The JLS ([15.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3)) states the following:

> "The keyword this may be used only in the body of an instance method or default method, or in the body of a constructor of a class, or in an instance initializer of a class, or in the initializer of an instance variable of a class. If it appears anywhere else, a compile-time error occurs."
>
> "When used as a primary expression, the keyword this denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method or default method was invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed."

As you can see:

1. the `this` keyword can only appear in a context in where there *is* a current object, and
2. the value of `this` (when used as an expression) is always the reference to the current object; there is no mention of any case where it could be `null`.

(See also: [Can "this" ever be null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789528/can-this-ever-be-null-in-java))

---

The object that `this` refers to is not fully initialized at that point, but that isn't the cause of the exception  you are seeing. The cause of the NPE is something else.

Specifically, if an NPE is being thrown at that line, then *either* `f` is `null` *or* `f.getBars()` is returning `null`.  And looking at how you have coded the `Foo` class, the latter is definitely plausible.  (You don't initialize the `bars` member ... so it will be `null`.)

Answer (score 0):

Because `bars` is not initialized, whenever you call `f.getBars()` it returns a `null` object. When you try to call `.add()` on a `null` object, you get a `NullPointerException`.

Change

```
private ArrayList<Bar> bars;
```

to

```
private ArrayList<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();
```

or add

```
public Foo(){this.bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();}
```

to your `Foo` class.